# I am getting this error on Excel "Object library invalid or containing reference to object definitions that could not be found"

Tags: excel, vba, office365

Whenever I am running a Macro on a particular Excel File I get the above error. I only got this error after copying over Macros from a file I had when I had finished when on Windows 10 (I am now Running Windows 11).

I have deleted EXD Files and Cleared Cache but neither of these solutions worked.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check under Tools...References in the VB Editor... it should show you what the missing reference is there.

Comment: @Brax 'Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

   If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
   If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("H7:L7")) Is Nothing Then
   Target.Cells.Value = ""
   End If

End Sub'

Comment: @Brax thankyou. I don't exactly know what is missing? only boxes ticked were Visual Basic, Microsoft Excel 16.0 Library, OLE automation, Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library. I then ticked Microsoft Access Object Library 16.0 but it still was coming up with error on some sheets. But then I found when I deleted this Macro the error went away? 'Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

   If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
   If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("H7:L7")) Is Nothing Then
   Target.Cells.Value = ""
   End If

End Sub'

Comment: Also how do I display code on here so it's distinguished from the comment?

Comment: Sounds like you had a missing reference that you did not need. Removing it fixed the problem then, right? If you are going to post code, edit your question and put it there, not in a comment, as code in comments have limitations on how you can format them.